# What is the best way of writing the interrupt handler function?

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt

I always use a flag variable in interrupt handler function which will be set when interrupt function executes. I always keep check of this flag in main function and perform required operation ***(My whole application usually lies inside while(1) loop in main function)***. I don't know if this is the best way to do. Can anyone throw some light on best practices of writing a interrupt handler function. And is it good to use blocking functions inside a interrupt handler?

Comment: https://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4397803/Interrupts-short-and-simple--Part-1---Good-programming-practices

Comment: Your question is not easy to answer. It depends on the peripheral the ISR is for. In general you should write the routine as short as possible to minimize jitter and delay. If you have a RTOS like freeRTOS you can use some of the IPC mechanisms to transfer data from ISR to the task context. And no you should avoid using any blocking function within an ISR.

Comment: @JonnySchubert Thank you.

Comment: In non-embedded systems, it is not unreasonable to have a file-scope variable `static volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;` and for the signal handler to simply set that: `static void sig_handler(int signum) { flag = signum; }` etc.  Indeed, in standard C, that is one of the few things you're allowed to do. The rules in an embedded environment could be (usually are) quite different, and you need to study the documentation with care. Calling blocking functions in an interrupt handler is usually a bad idea. You usually want the handler to return ASAP (or quicker). But YMMV — it depends on the system.

Comment: The way you describe is generally a good way to do things, but there can  be exceptions depending on the peripheral for when there's something you need to take care of immediately in an ISR rather than setting a flag and polling it in main().  A that's always worth following though, you should spend as little time as possible in an ISR.  Looping code inside an ISR should be used with care to ensure you won't get stuck.  Another tip is that variables that change in an ISR should be declared as volatile so the compiler can't make assumptions about their value (since they can change at any time).

Comment: There is no right answer...It is determined by your system design.  There are event driven mcu/embedded applications that are wholly contained in the interrupt handler(s).  there are polling driven that are wholly contained in the main() and everything in between.  Doing your system engineering is the key, how much time worst case do you have anywhere in the foreground application for an interrupt, is your whole design based on responding to interrupts are are there foreground tasks.  you isr cannot exceed the worst case interruption of any of the other tasks at hand (combined).

Comment: using a flag for the forground is a common solution but it has a latency that is either deterministic or not based on your system design.  if that interrupt needs to be handled in a deterministic amount of a time leaving a flag for the foreground task likely wont work, but it depends on your design and analysis of the big loop.  sometimes you have to sprinke a test for the flag at multiple places in the loop, or redesign the loop or state machine.

Comment: [This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329339/avoiding-global-variables-when-using-interrupts-in-embedded-systems/329961#329961) from EE should answer the question.

Comment: @JonnySchubert Please don't read or recommend articles from embedded.com. Anyone and their mother writes articles there, and they are quite often of low quality. On several occasions I have lectured the authors of articles there about embedded programming basics. That particular article is naively written, teaching hobbyist-level methods. And there's a fat, blatant beginner bug on the first page of the article: no `volatile` (or `static`) for the variable shared with the ISR. Embedded.com is nowadays a trash site with trash articles; they used to limit article writing to gurus only.